# How do I combine two objects in SOQL for a simple join? I just a list of users with their profile

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am trying to do a simple join between the user object and profile object. They are connected by ID
User = profileID
Profile = ID

This would be a simple query in SQL:
select u.name, u.profileID, p.name, p.ID 
from Users
Join Profile
ON u.profileID = p.ID

I've tried the following and all I get are errors:
Select User.name, (SELECT profile.name, profileID from Profile) from User

select name, profileID, userRoleId from User WHERE ProfileId IN (select name from Profile)

SELECT User.name, user.profileId (SELECT profile.name FROM Profile) 
FROM User 
Where User.ProfileId IN ( Select Profile.ID from Profile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for following FK relationships, you use the compound name as the field to query, e.g.

```
select name, profile.name from user
```

See the [SOQL relationships docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) for more details.